# Discontinuous Galerkin order of convergence on arbirary refined mesh: step-12 deal.ii tutorial

Tags: finite-element, convergence, hyperbolic-pde, discontinuous-galerkin, advection

I'm learning DG methods and in order to practice a little bit I'm using the deal.ii library. In particular, I'm looking at [step-12](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_12.html), where they solve

$$\operatorname{div}(\beta u) = 0$$
$$u = g_D \text{ on } \Gamma^-$$

for a field $\beta$ and a discontinuous data on the inflow boundary.

**In order to verify the order of convergence**, I decided to construct a manufactured solution $$U(x,y)=e^x \sin(y)$$ using as field $\beta =(-y,x)$ which is the same as the one they have, but not scaled to one. In this way, the inflow boundary is the same as before, namely the lower and right boundaries. The equation then becomes

$$\operatorname{div}(\beta u) = e^x(\cos(y)x  \sin(y) y)$$
$$u=U_{|\Gamma^-}$$ As you can read in the [possible extension section](https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/step_12.html#Possibilitiesforextensions), they say that

> one can prove that for elements of degree p, the order of convergence is $p + \frac{1}{2}$ on arbitrary meshes

In my case $p=1$ so I should get order $\frac{3}{2}$ in the $L^2$ norm, **but** here's what I get (by using `reduction_rate_log2` in the `ConvergenceTable` class)

```
cycle cells dofs        L2             H1       
    0    64   256 9.776e-04    - 5.471e-02    - 
    1   121   484 6.739e-04 0.54 4.156e-02 0.40 
    2   220   880 4.225e-04 0.67 3.323e-02 0.32 
    3   409  1636 2.138e-04 0.98 2.326e-02 0.51 
    4   757  3028 1.203e-04 0.83 1.720e-02 0.44 
    5  1399  5596 7.136e-05 0.75 1.311e-02 0.39 
    6  2575 10300 3.567e-05 1.00 9.398e-03 0.48 
    7  4699 18796 1.991e-05 0.84 7.059e-03 0.41 
    8  8635 34540 1.037e-05 0.94 5.142e-03 0.46 
    9 15799 63196 5.284e-06 0.97 3.727e-03 0.46
```

**Question: Is that correct? I mean, does this agree with the theoretical bound of order $\frac{3}{2}$?**

To confirm the goodness of my code, which is essentially the same as the step-12, with the obvious fixes (namely, the assembly, the definition of the exact solution and the change in the scaling of $\beta$) here's what I have by refining globally the mesh:

```
cycle cells  dofs        L2             H1

0    64    256 9.776e-04    - 5.471e-02    - 

1   256   1024 2.463e-04 1.99 2.744e-02 1.00 

2  1024   4096 6.180e-05 1.99 1.373e-02 1.00 

3  4096  16384 1.548e-05 2.00 6.871e-03 1.00 

4 16384  65536 3.873e-06 2.00 3.436e-03 1.00 

5 65536 262144 9.686e-07 2.00 1.718e-03 1.00
```

The $L^2$ error and $H^1$ error converge properly, as you can see from the following table so I think that there are no mistakes in my code actually.

---

**EDIT:**

As you may see, the EOC in $H^1$ drops after a certain number of dofs. How can I justify this?

```
cells  dofs     u_L2_norm      u_H1_norm    
   64    1024 9.679e-08    - 1.223e-05    - 
  256    4096 6.045e-09 4.00 1.532e-06 3.00 
 1024   16384 3.777e-10 4.00 1.918e-07 3.00 
 4096   65536 2.360e-11 4.00 2.556e-08 2.91 
16384  262144 1.475e-12 4.00 9.353e-09 1.45 
65536 1048576 9.528e-14 3.95 8.801e-09 0.09
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are solving a two dimensional problem:

Your refinement in your first example is not $\frac{\Delta x}{2}$. Generally this does not make problems if you refine uniformly. If you look a the number of elements, the error and the EOC something does not match. I am no expert for **deal.ii**, but i think the EOC routine is not able to handle different refinement levels other than $\frac{\Delta x}{2}$.

You have to use something like: ($N$ = number of elements, $\epsilon$ = error)

$\text{EOC}= \log\left(\frac{\epsilon_{1}}{\epsilon_{2}}\right)/\log\left(\sqrt{\frac{N_{1}}{ N_{2}}}\right)$

A good example, why i am not a big fan of learning computational science via **blackbox** libraries.

Regards

Comment: Thanks @ConvexHull (nice nick !) That was my suspect. One question: what I should observe is order $p+1$ in $L^2$ and $p$ in $H^1$, using uniformly refined meshes?

Comment: Yes you should observe these EOC's. About $H^1$ I am not sure.

Comment: You need not have uniform refinements for convergence studies. You can choose element sizes arbitrarily and adjust the element size appropriately when calculating the convergence rate. The slope on log-log plot should be (p+1) (for L2); it does not matter which points you choose.

Comment: @Chenna K Uniform refinement does not exclude arbitrary element sizes. At the end you have to calculate a global EOC. How would you proceed  if each element is refined differently.

Comment: @ChennaK Thanks for you comment. Do you know what order I should observe in $H^1$ norm?

Comment: @ConvexHull, true! The element size can be arbitrary but the mesh should be uniform.

Comment: @bobinthebox, the convergence rate in the H1 norm should be at least p.

Comment: Uhm, then there must be something strange: if I increase the order of my elements to $p=3$, I see correctly that the $L^2$ norm is 4, but in $H^1$ as the number of dofs increase the order drops (see the edit). How is that possible? @ChennaK

Comment: You reached the round-off error limit? How is $H^1$ calculated?

Comment: I was thinking to roundoff too, but as you can see we have smaller errors in $L^2$ (in terms of orders of magnitude) but the order is still correct. So it seems strange to me that the $H^1$ drops out in that way. Btw, what the library does is written here
(https://www.dealii.org/current/doxygen/deal.II/namespaceVectorTools.html#a676190d2c897ac5da68a9c460fa95832). @ConvexHull

Comment: That doesn't matter. The $H^1$ norm is a euclidinal combination of $L_2$ and $H_1$ seminorm. The seminorm is based on the gradient of the error. I am quite sure you are facing round-off error problems. My advice: Try to implement more on your own, otherwise you won't be able to understand your problems.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @ConvexHull, much appreciated :-) Actually, I've just started using the library: I've been doing things by myself in the classical Galerkin methods in the last year. And I don't think it's easy to have a dimension independent program that can use arbitrary degree polynomials for a DG discretization. Also, I think deal.ii is the best library out there: you need to take care of lots of details, quadratures, assembly, linear solver, MPI,etc... it's not a black-box like FEnics

Comment: @bobinthebox Sure, it's not easy and quite time consuming. You should not try to reinvent the wheel. However, there is no free lunch.

Comment: @bobinthebox. Try (i) p=2 and (ii) repeat the study by starting from a different mesh. For example, if you are starting with a 5x5 mesh now, then start with 6x6 etc. If the convergence behaviour repeats, then there might be a bug in the implementation.

Comment: @ChennaK and others. I've just tried to check the OP problem by using two different facilities provided by the library. I think the OP is using the ParsedConvergenceTable class. If you try the same with a classical ConvergenceTable class, then you have the correct rates also for the H^1 norm. I think the issue is that if you don't provide the exact gradient of the solution as  a parameter, then an approximation of $\nabla u$ is computed, and this may easily corrupt the rate.

Comment: @VoB An approximation of the exact gradient is no good idea. Even with a high sampling rate. How much DOFs does deal.ii use to integrate the error norms? Perhaps one can increase it.

Comment: For sure it's not a good way. That's what I meant. The difference in the two approaches I used is that in the "classical" way I provide the the exact solution **and its gradient**, while in the OP's way he only provides the expression for the solution, not its gradient. So I honestly don't know what the library does when it comes to compute the $H^1$ norm of the error. If it were doing some symbolic stuff, then we shouldn't have problems. That's why I suspect that some approximation is going on @ConvexHull

Comment: @VoB, in that case, it would be worth modifying the code to compute the error norms manually. Should be relatively straightforward to copy the existing for-loop over elements and modify it appropriately for computing errors.

Comment: @ChennaK Which code are you referring to?